# Use of the word provincia for other countries provinces

Tags: word-meaning, name

Why do Italians put the word provincia only for provinces in Italy but not for the  province names of other countries?

Comment: What do you mean? We use it, for instance, for Canada's provinces. Which other countries have actual “provinces” (as opposed to states, counties, Länder, cantons and so on)?

Comment: I see [here](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guip%C3%BAzcoa) "provincia" used for a Spanish province.

Comment: The question, as it stands, asks “Why is it the case that X?”, while X isn't actually the case. It should either rephrased to be meaningful or closed.

Comment: See [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/canada) for Canada's _province_ (there even is a section “Sviluppo delle province”), for instance, and [here for Spain's](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/spagna).

Comment: You are bringing few instances, mostly from Treccani. My question was about "Italians". Do you hear this also in informal conversation?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: I am confused: the texts I mentioned are written by Italians for Italians. Canadian (or other) provinces are not a frequent conversation topic, but whenever they are mentioned they are called _province_.

Comment: Spoken Italian is different than written Italian. No confusion

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti Could you clarify what do you think Italians use instead of *province*? Because I have no clue of what you mean...

Comment: @DenisNardin Sorry but your question is put in a way that I have to repeat my question again and say that my question is not what you claim. I said : some Italian friends of mine told me that province is used only for Italian provinces. I should not go search what they use instead. This is not the question here

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti And what we are telling you is that you should ask your Italian friends what they mean, because we're quite baffled by this statement. Of course we Italians don't call German Bezirke or the English counties "province" (why would we? the names translate to *distretti* and *contee* respectively), but beyond this obvious observation I at least don't know what to tell you... Maybe you can add more context to help us figure out where's the mismatch

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti, there are three "Needs details or clarity" closing votes and several comments expressing puzzlement about the meaning of your question. Might you do something?

Comment: The problems is the more I explain the more confusion you and Denise create, just because you don't believe what I said. There are countries which use province name

Comment: I mean, you have even answered correctly enough why more discussion?

Answer (score 6):

Canadian (or other) provinces are not a frequent conversation topic, but whenever they are mentioned they are called *province*. This is confirmed by atlases and reference books, and I can assure you that informal Italian has not coined a different special term for them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the case, but if you are speaking about news in Italy about foreign countries there are several possible reasons:

- the province is called something else (county in the UK) or it
  doesn't always exist
- the foreign country has provinces but their importance and
  differentiation at the cultural level is way weaker that the one in Italy

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE and thanks for your contribution. This post seems to me more like a personal opinion than an answer (but maybe the problem is that we are trying to find some reason to something which doesn't really happen).

Comment: This is not my opinion, I have heard it from my Italian friends